# How can I construct a block! containing parens?

Tags: red

I have a block of words like `[x y]` and I want to make a block of `[x: (x) y: (y)]`

This doesn't quite work:

```
>> b: [x y]
== [x y]
>> collect [foreach w b [keep to-set-word w keep to-paren w]]
== [x: x y: y]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keep` relies on a `append` action when collecting the argument value, so a `paren!` argument will see each contained values appended, instead of the whole paren series (same as for any other `any-block!` type). In order to append the paren series as a single value, use `keep/only` (which will then use `append/only` internally).

```
>> b: [x y]
== [x y]
>> collect [foreach w b [keep to-set-word w keep/only to-paren w]]
== [x: (x) y: (y)]
```